# Stick columns to the left and top in a table-like structure made out of divs

Tags: html, css, position, sticky

I have a table-like structure made out of different divs (and not the html  tag). (kind of like an excel view).

I want to implement the fixation of the top row (header) and the first column (has some actions).

All my actions are in one view. Every row with data is a separate view and the header is a separate view.

I have presently applied position: sticky/-webkit-sticky and top: 0/left:0 as required.

This has been able to fix my problem in most browsers. However, Safari is behaving very abnormally.

My left column gets to stay fixed, but the top column on scrolling goes out of the viewPort.

Can anybody suggest some other fix or a Safari related fix?

Please find images attached below:

[image: Fixed Left Column]

[image: Fixed Top Row]

Answer (score 0):

Sticky can be finicky. If you showed us relevant html/css it would be easier to offer solutions.

Is there a reason you can't use `position: fixed;` instead of sticky? unless the sticky elements are only sometimes sticky, then fixed should work.

Or maybe set the body 100% width and height, `overflow: none;` and then set the area you want scrollable to 100% height with `overflow-y: scroll` or 'auto'.

Edit: Based on your comments below.

I think I have a better idea about what you are trying to do. You want the left column to scroll up/down with the rows, but not left/right. `position: sticky;` may be the only way to achieve that other than javascript.

I think you should take the top row out of the equation though. Put the whole thing in one container, then setup nested containers within that. There are lots of different ways to structure it. Because `position: sticky;` gets positioned relative to the nearest scrollable ancestor.

I made a jsfiddle to show one possible method. https://jsfiddle.net/c9kaz854/4/ I can't test it in safari right now, but maybe you can test it, and maybe it can give you some different ideas.

I would suggest you make the same sort of structure you are going for in a simplified format. Start with a clean html file and basic css reset file. Build the basic structure and tweak it until you have something that works consistently across the browsers you need to support. Then use that basic pattern in your full site.

Comment: Using the `position: fixed`, fixes my elements relative to a super-super parent div. Which obviously causes a big distortion to my views. I cannot make changes to other divs as that would mess up a lot of other things, which would take up a loooootttt of effort.
Regarding the 2nd suggestion: what do you mean by body 100% width and height? What is `body` here?

Comment: I have tried to show the html/css code via the images attached. The relevant code can be seen in the web-inspector

Comment: Sorry for the delay, something came up earlier. Trying to throw together a jsfiddle to show you now.

Comment: Edited my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Because `position: sticky;` has inconsistent implementations in some browsers, a possible workaround for your situation could be to put the element in an `<iframe>`, `<object>` or `<embed>`. Then you could used `position: fixed;` in a more limited context.

To make that work though, you would put the top row above and outside the iframe, and all the scrollable content inside the iframe (left column and all but top row). Just have left column (inside iframe) be 'fixed.' Put the iframe in a div with `overflow-y: scroll;` (or auto), and make the iframe itself taller than its container div, so for vertical the scrolling happens outside the iframe, and the whole iframe element scrolls within the containing div, including the left column which is fixed inside the iframe. Then put a class on the iframe source's html/body elements and limit their width with `width: 100%;` (size of the container) and give them `overflow-x: scroll;` (or auto), so the the horizontal scrolling happens within the iframe where the left column is fixed and won't move.